# Tablix column orders position is misplaced

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

One of my reports is using Tablix which is based on stored procedure. 
One of the columns is actually group of columns for time periods which should be in that order from left to right. 
Yesterday, Last 7 days , Last 2 weeks , Last 3 weeks. 
Problem is that when I'm viewing the report I get this wrong order :
Yesterday, Last 7 days  Last 3 weeks ,Last 2 weeks .
Is there a way I can control the order ?
Screenshot attached:

[image: Screenshot]

Please advise, 
Thank you 
Raffi Begas

Comment: Add another field on which do your sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number of columns is reasonably small, you could use a simple `SWITCH` statement to your column group sort, so instead of sorting on the name which it is probably doing as default, replace that with something like.

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!MyTimePeriodField.Value = "Yesterday", 1,
    Fields!MyTimePeriodField.Value = "Last 7 Days", 2,
    Fields!MyTimePeriodField.Value = "Last 2 Weeks", 3,
    Fields!MyTimePeriodField.Value = "Last 3 Weeks", 4,
    True, 99
    )
```

Add more lines as required, the final `True, 99` just catches anything that does not match the previous pairs.

use this as your Column Group Sort and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be sorting on the Column name, try renaming the columns in your sp to be "01 Yesterday" ,"02 7 Days", "03 2 Weeks"

you can then sub-string the field when displaying if you do not wan the prefix